# fit footer on bottom of viewport on dynamically page height changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want fit my page footer bottom of the view port when my page content height is less than the height of view port. If the page height exceeds that of the view port, the footer should go below that content.

I have checked height of the view port and changed that. But on some scenarios it's not working.

HTML:

```
<div id="page" class="page">
    <div id="header"></div>

    <div id="contentWrapper"></div>

    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
        var vpHeight = getViewPort().height;
        var contentHeight = $("#contentWrapper").height();

        if (contentHeight < vpHeight) {
            $("#footer").css("position", "absolute");
            $("#footer").css("bottom", "0");
            $("#goToTop").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#footer").css("position", "static");
            $("#footer").css("bottom", "auto");
            $("#goToTop").show();
        }


 function getViewPort() {
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window)) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }

    return { width: e[a + 'Width'], height: e[a + 'Height'] }
};
```

Comment: create a fiddle please, or post your html too

Comment: @SarathSprakash: "And", not "or" (well, the *fiddle* is optional; the HTML is not).

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="page" class="page">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="contentWrapper"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Try that example:

```
<body>
<div class="page-wrapper">

<div class="page-buffer"></div>
</div>
<div class="page-footer">

</div>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.page-wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
* html .page-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
.page-buffer {
    height: 50px;
}
```

It should work and you don't need JS in that case.

The original article was written and in russian:
http://www.zakharov.ms/footer/
But you can use chrome translate function to get how it works.

Comment: Thanks its working with some modifications. I have moved my footer outside from page wrapper. Then as per browser type i have changed html,body{height:value%}. For if IE_> height:97% means footer is fits on viewport bottom. For Chrome and Firefox > height:97.3% and 98% respectively. Once again thanks for your help MR.Artem_g

Comment: Okay, good! Could you click on the green check mark on the left of the answer to tell others that the solution has worked? =)

Comment: What if 50px footer height is changing dynamically?

Comment: Use javascript to watch height